# How to add a new reference to a firestore object

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

What I'm trying to do is to add a new reference to this object:

[image: Firestore]

Just insert a new element inside "citas". This is what I have so far.

```
database.collection('NegociosDev').doc('Peluquerías')
    .collection('Negocios').doc('PR01').collection('empleados').where('Nombre', '==','Ale')...
```

I guess I shouldn't use "add()" as it is used to add a new document right? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you should update your document [this way](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/c8e42f4723f35bb077042740d2b2473d1cbad744/firestore/test.firestore.js#L472-L482):

```js
database.collection('NegociosDev').doc('Peluquerías').update({
   citas: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("new value")
})
```